# RC peak detector calculation

Tags: capacitor, resistors, circuit-design, ac, sensor

[image]

### Before the edit was made

I have a signal that is an AC signal and I would like to track its envelope. I'm not doing AM, I'm trying to make a transducer for my sensor. Frequency is constant but amplitude changes from 1 to 3 volts based upon value from the sensor. I would like for the output voltage to be able to follow changes of the input in maximum of 300ms while having minimal ripple. I would like to calculate values for R and C and not guess them. All of the calculations I have found were about AM but I don't really have a carrier signal.

---

Edit: It looks like I have made a mistake and mixed some terms. Sorry for wasting some of yours time. I was looking for a peak detector actually. Diode voltage drop does not bother me. I was looking on how to calculate R and C, for an input signal of 770 Hz with an amplitude ranging from 1V to 3V, so that the output reaches peak within maximum of 300ms. I would like a somewhat realtime measurement so that's why 300ms but preferiably in much less time with again somewhat smooth voltage level.

---

Edit: changed the title from "Envelope detector circuit" to "RC peak detector calculation"

Comment: In fact you do have a carrier signal and you have described AM (Amplitude Modulation).

Comment: Do you want analog circuitry ? Or digital one ?

Comment: Analog, specifically what is shown on image.

Comment: What about a classic opamp-diode peak detector like shown [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/30638/95488)? New peaks are tracked immediately. RC determines how fast old peaks decay.

Comment: @ErikR I don't want to over complicate things and using only a diode, resistor and a capacitor is cheaper and acceptable for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s what the math looks like for your example.

The worst case (fastest changing) is if your input suddenly changes from 3V rms (4.2V peak) to 1V rms (1.4V peak).
In that case you want your detector to pick up the new peak in no more than 300ms.

Ignoring the diode drop, the capacitor will be charged to 4.2V and then start an exponential decay towards zero until the new peak at 1.4V is hit at which point the cap will stay charged there.

If I did my math right (below) the RC time constant should be .27, so C=1uF and R=270K would work.
(If you want to take into account the diode drop, subtract 0.6 from the 4.2V and 1.4V in the equation.)

[image]

[image]

This is the maximum RC to meet your 300ms spec: anything larger, it would take longer than 300ms to find new peak.

The minimum RC would be if you want the peak detector to track as fast as possible. In this case, the fastest it needs to track is a drop from 4.2V peak to 1.4V peak in one period of your 770Hz signal (which has a period of 1.3ms).
[image]

Use the same formula with t=.0013 to get an RC of .0012 for this quick delay.
If RC made any smaller than this, it’s moving faster than it needs to.

So your desired RC is bounded between .0013 (fast but lots of ripple) and 0.27 (slow but no ripple).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, I saw the formula but used it wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

You can always start with the RC time constant.

[image]

*Figure 1. Capacitor charge and discharge curves. Image source: [PCBway](https://www.pcbway.com/project/share/How_to_build_the_relay_sequencer.html).*

In your case V1 is going to charge C1 as the V1 voltage rises. When V1 falls away C1 will discharge through R1 giving a voltage discharge curve similar to the right-hand side of the curve in Figure 1. There are a few numbers you should remember:

- At τ = RC the voltage will have fallen to 37% of the value it had at t = 0.
- At 3τ the voltage will have fallen to about 5% of the value it had at t = 0.
- At 5τ the voltage will have fallen to about 1% of the value it had at t = 0.

You're going to have to trade off speed of response against smoothness of output waveform. Fast response will give high ripple.

Since you seem to have a simulator available I recommend that you pick some values and try them out to see if it's possible to get an acceptable solution with such a simple filter.

Comment: To be clear - only the discharge case is affected by R1 in this case. The charge time will be very fast, limited only by the source resistance.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your sinusoid is 770 Hz. The selection R.C filter at the output is constrained at the upper frequency level by this 770 Hz and at the lower level  by the bandwidth of the signal you are detecting.

If you want a response of 300 ms (you could be more precise in this requirement -- is this the time to respond to a 'step' change in input level ? Is this requirement to reach 90 % of the final value etc.).

There are also tradeoffs in ripple vs. response. However the largest errors in your circuit will actually come from the diode which is a) nonlinear, and b) takes a varying, but approximately 0.7 V from the output. There is no point in optimizing the other errors to be significantly less than this one.

If you pick an R.C product of value T, then the ripple (from the 770 Hz) will be how much the output voltage decays in a time 1/770 s. For T >> 1/770, this will be about a fraction 1/(T*770) of the actual voltage (the ripple isn't a fixed value, but more a percentage of the output voltage).

For fast response, perhaps a T of 100 ms would be a reasonable balance.

Then you would have:
Ripple = 1/(0.1*770) = 1.2 % of the output
Response: in 300ms, you would reach approximately [1-exp(-3)], or 95 % of the final value.

Answer (score 0):

With a diode and a capacitor it would be a peak detector. Adding the resistor to allow discharge it becomes a quasi-peak detector. It was already discussed in SE [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177137/quasi-peak-detector). Have a look at the calculation there, that includes a series resistor R1 (that you can remove) and the parallel resistor R2.

$$\tau_C = (R_1 || R_2) C = \frac{R_1 R_2}{R_1 + R_2} C$$

For an accurate measurement if low voltage values are involved (comparable with diode voltage drop) you may use a "precision rectifier" or "zero drop rectifier", made with an OpAmp as in sketch. (kept "C" and 'R2"s in the previous SE schematic and formula)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN0K26.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/196607/95488

you want to make \$f_0\$ much larger than the largest frequency component in your input signal that you want to preserve. Call this frequency \$f_d\$. Note that if your input signal is a square wave you'll want to use a higher multiple of the square wave frequency, like 5 times as suggested by the comments.

What is "much larger"? That will require some experimentation, but usually this means at least 10x. In the question's example a value of 25 times \$f_d\$ was used for \$f_0\$.